# How to on Ubuntu synchronize software built from source?

Tags: sync, source-code, organizer-software

I have three computers with Ubuntu. I know how that there's a way to synchronize packages installed from the Ubuntu Software Center, but... what if I want to synchronize software from source? Do you have any idea how might do that?

Thanks.

Comment: So you want to make one of your PCs a local repository?

Comment: This should be the idea...

Answer (score 0):

Build a PPA, compile, distribute.

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas